# Decrypting a substitution cipher, but with symbols instead of letters

Tags: substitution-cipher

I'm trying to decipher a message encrypted by a substitution cipher (probably a monosubstitution). But the problem is, that we have symbols instead of letters (letters were substituted for random symbols). What would be the best way to decrypt such a message?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you suppose symbols instead of letters make a difference?  On computers they're stored as strings of bits, not as letters _per se_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) is the way to go. If your plaintext is in English then the letter "e" would (probably) be the most common letter in the text. A good technique would also be to look for repeated symbols. In the English language (and probably all other languages as well) there are many words with double letters (i.e. "ki**ll**", "he**ll**o", "sy**mm**etry"), so you can narrow it down what the word with the repeated symbol would be.

Comment: If you want to run the encryption through a program that only analyzes letters, assign letters to the symbols.